# Создание терминальной php команды

Tags: php

У разных фреймворков есть разные терминальные команды, которые взаимодействуют с файлами. Например, в ларавеле `php artisan migrate`. Как их создают и как они работают? С чего вообще стоит начать поиск?

Это суто для моего скелетона, но мне было бы очень удобно иметь команду, которая брала бы список статусов с класса такого вида[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и апдейтила в базе поле status (типа enum) и добавляла статусы.

Извините, пожалуйста, если плохо обьяснила

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Терминальные команды пишутся ровно по тому же принципу что и контроллеры в MVC

Для терминальных команд делают такую же единую точку входа, как и для веба.
Точно так же в ней подключают ядро.
Точно так же пишут подобие роутера, которое по переданному параметру определяет, какой скрипт запускать
И точно так же скрипт обращается к нужным моделям и выполняет их методы.

Comment: Что такое *МВЦ*?

Comment: но как их делают именными? я имею ввиду, все знаю что php скрипт можно запустить коммандой вида `php script.php`, но как создают комманды типа migrate?

Comment: типа migrate или типа artisan? Про типа migrate  я написал выше - делается роутер. Ну или Симфони например просто просматривает все файлы команд и ищет нужную

Comment: Да, я видела что с помощью ларавеля можно создать роут и комманду, но на чистом пхп как это делается?

Comment: нету никакой магии, специальной команды, которой на вход подаешь название и она тебе говорит какой скрипт запукать. Все делается руками. пишешь в своем коде, если параметр migrate - запускаешь migrate.php. И так далее. Понятно?

Answer (score 0):

По сути, консольные команды обрабатывает обработчик (у Laravel это файл artisan, который скорее есть точка входа, нежели сам обработчик), а уже далее он использует параметры команды для дальнейшей работы.

Как вам написал @Ипатьев, если вы напишете migrate после artisan, то migrate - это строка, и с ней можно сделать, к примеру, загрузку и запуск файла/класса или чего ещё на основе строки migrate.

Если напишете migrate down:1 - это тоже можно использовать и извлечь данные из параметров. У Laravel, к примеру, есть помощник, который обрабатывает эти параметры и помещает их в переменные для дальнейшей работы с ними.